# Laravel 5.8 null csrf_token() when used in api controller

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5.8, csrf-token, laravel-api

I'm working on Laravel 5.8 and php 7.1.3. using csrf_token() return value in controller function but not return any value in controllers/api controller. how to used csrf_token in api controller function.

Api controller :- Http/Controllers/Api/TestConroller.php

```
class TestConroller extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        
    }

    public function getToken(Request $request){

        echo csrf_token();
    }
}
```

Routes:- routes/api.php

```
Route::get('getToken', 'Api\TestConroller@getToken');
```

url:-

```
http://localhost/laravel/api/getToken
```

if csrf token() not work in api controller then how to used token for verification in api.

Comment: On your GET method, Your parameter has some name? then `$request->name` if you dont know the name of the param, then you can get it with `dd($request->all());`

Comment: I mean you should use `return` over `echo` in Laravel controllers, like `return response()->json(['csrf_token' => csrf_token()]);`, but Api's typically don't use `csrf_tokens`, so I'm not sure what you're really trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 0):

`Csrf` token only works in `web.php`  not in `api.php` .Api's are stateless

if you check `kernal.php`

```
 protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\HandleInertiaRequests::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];
```

web middleware uses session .So For testing purpose if you comment below middleware

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
```

then it will return null on web.php

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use in api.php just add these 2 lines in kernel.php

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
```

in

```
'api' => [
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
```

section